# Why is the cyclomatic complexity equal to two for a simple Hello World?

Tags: programming-languages, theory, metrics

I would have two questions related to cyclomatic complexity:

1. Can I use this metric for a whole app? I guess I cannot, as it would be incredibly large number, considering functions calling functions etc. Is it just for module/method/unit?
2. In Visual Studio, for starting app with just calling the `Main` method, the cyclomatic complexity value is 2. Why? There is just one possible way if I run the program - it ends.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The cyclomatic complexity of the most basic console application is 2 for a simple reason: aside the `Main()` method, there is also a constructor. It's like writing:

```
public class Program
{
    public Program()
    {
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
    }
}
```

- The first path is to create a new instance of the `Program` class. This path is taken by default to launch the application.
- The second path is to call the static method `Program.Main()`. This path can be taken if the application is used as an ordinary library by another application.

Note that this applies to any non-static class having a static method. For example:

```
public class Hello
{
    // Even if the constructor was omitted, it will still be added by the compiler.
    public static void SayHello()
    {
    }
}
```

will have a cyclomatic complexity of 2 as well.

Also note that if you really want to have an application with a cyclomatic complexity of 1, you simply declare `Program` class as static, as in the following piece of code. I have no idea why the default template in Visual Studio forgets to add both `public` and `static` keywords.

```
public static class Program // ← See, we replaced a non-static class by a static one
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

As for your first question, you don't use cyclomatic complexity as the sole factor. Maintainability index, with its [quite tricky formula](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/codeanalysis/maintainability-index-range-and-meaning), is a better metric, but even maintainability index is not something you can fully trust and rely on to say that a piece of code is "good" or "bad".

It's not disturbing to have a cyclomatic complexity of a few thousands for a small project, and it doesn't make too much sense to use it for class, assembly or project scope; what would be much more disturbing is to obtain a high cyclomatic complexity for a specific method.

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize that (as for the point 2). For the first one, also CC calculation is useful really only for modules or algoritms, correct?

Comment: @user970696: it's useful for methods (including getters and setters of properties). If you have a method with a cyclomatic complexity of 5 000, this is a hint that something might be totally wrong with this method.

Comment: Also, the cyclomatic complexity gives you a lower bound on the number of test cases you need to achieve 100% C1 code coverage. In @MainMa's example, you need at least 5000 non-overlapping `assert`s to achieve 100% C1 coverage. (The same applies to NPath complexity and C2 coverage.)

Comment: Of course, this answer has "everything must be a member function" glasses. C / C++, for instance, don't have this behavior.